# knife ssh with multiple jump hosts

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a network that requires two jump hosts to get into from my workstation. My ~/.ssh/config looks like this:

`Host *.mgmt.example.com
  ProxyJump admin-1.prod.example.com,jump-1.example.com`

This works fine for regular ssh but I can't seem to get knife ssh to connect. I tried adding `--ssh-gateway admin-1.prod.example.com,jump-2.example.com` to the command but it also doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have knife ssh go through two proxies?

An example command based on the .ssh/config entry above:
`knife ssh "name:host-1.mgmt.example.com" "hostname"`

```
numb3rs1x@workstation~:chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.2.30
chef-client version: 14.4.56
delivery version: master (6862f27aba89109a9630f0b6c6798efec56b4efe)
berks version: 7.0.6
kitchen version: 1.23.2
inspec version: 2.2.70

numb3rs1x@workstation~:knife ssh "name:host-1.mgmt.example.com" "hostname" -a fqdn
WARNING: Failed to connect to host-1.mgmt.example.com -- Net::SSH::Proxy::ConnectError: command timed out: ssh -J jump-1.example.com -W host-1.mgmt.example.com:22 admin-1.prod.example.com
ssh: connect to host jump-1.example.com port 22: Operation timed out
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

numb3rs1x@workstation~:ssh host-1.mgmt.example.com
Warning: Permanently added 'admin-1.prod.example.com,10.5.0.9' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Warning: Permanently added 'jump-1.example.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Warning: Permanently added 'host-1.mgmt.example.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
numb3rs1x@host-1:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

`net-ssh-gateway` doesn't directly support multiple hops, however the built-in proxyjump support in `net-ssh` should as long as you're on a very recent ChefDK. See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/commit/4ae3bb582b93787de0b7c91301318bf13b9c7012#diff-d81a1a91889532e56748e65ae9683a7c for details.

Comment: Are you saying that the `ProxyJump` settings in my `~/.ssh/config` should be supported or is there something I have to specify? I have the latest chefdk and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the full command you are running? You would need to be connecting via hostname (instead of IP) so that the `Host` glob activates.

Comment: I posted an example command in the question. I am using the hostname. I don't have any settings related to ProxyJump anywhere other than my `~/.ssh/config` at the moment.

Comment: What does Chef think the machines FQDN is? https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/2878c06b5287ce9415406738da7ccd3ed0ac0ebc/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb#L210-L226 is the code to compute the attribute name to connect to, or you can override that with the `-a` option to `knife ssh`. Make sure the name matches your glob. Also what version of ChefDK are you using?

Comment: The name I'm using does match the FQDN. I tried adding `-a fqdn` to the command just in case, but it doesn't seem tome a difference. I'll add output of an ssh vs knife ssh to the same host in the body of the main question for reference.

Comment: `ssh: connect to host jump-1.example.com port 22: Operation timed out`. There is a `.prod` in your example which isn't in that hostname. Sounds like something funky?

Comment: There are two jump hosts that ssh must traverse before hitting the mgmt network. The first is the `.prod.example.com` network and then from there it should go to the host at `.example.com` and then from that server it should be able to get to `.mgmt.example.com`. It seems to be timing out at `.example.com` which can't be reach directly from my workstation. I wonder if for some reason knife ssh isn't showing the proper source IP? If you look at my `~/.ssh/config` you'll see that both networks are accounted for and the example output there shows that it does work with just ssh.

Comment: I think you've mixed up your greeking in making your examples such that I can't follow it anymore. The code in net-ssh looks correct to me. I recommend tracing through that code with your actual values to see what is trying to run.

Comment: I cleaned up the examples so that the names are consistent. It seems like it's skipping `admin-1.prod.example.com` and going right for `jump-1.example.com`, which won't work since `jump-1.example.com` can only be accessed through `admin-1.prod.discogs.com`. In the straight ssh example, you can see that it starts at `admin-1.prod` and then goes through `jump-1` to finally get to `host-1.mgmt`.

Comment: +1000 for the ProxyJump support in net/ssh  THANKS!